# Time out a curl command shell script centOS

Tags: linux, shell, curl, timeout, sh

```
checkServer(){
    response=$(curl --connect-timeout 10  --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null localhost:8080/patuna/servicecheck)

    if [ "$response" = "200" ];
        then echo "`date --rfc-3339=seconds` -  Server is healthy, up and running"
        return 0
    else
        echo "`date --rfc-3339=seconds` -  Server is not healthy(response code - $response ), server is going to restrat"
        startTomcat
    fi
}
```

Here i want to time out the curl command but it dose not work. in centos7 Shell scrit. what i simply needs to do is timeout the curl command
    ERROR code is curl: option --connect-timeout=: is unknown

Comment: Shell is a programming language. I think either StackOverflow or  Super User or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checkServer(){
        response=$(curl --max-time 20 --connect-timeout 0  --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null localhost:8080/patuna/servicecheck)

        if [ "$response" = "200" ];
           then echo "`date --rfc-3339=seconds` -  Server is healthy, up and running"
           return 0
        else
           echo "`date --rfc-3339=seconds` -  Server is not healthy(response code - $response ), server is going to restrat"
           startTomcat
        fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the option of [`--max-time`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

> Maximum time in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take.  This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from hanging for hours due to  slow  networks  or  links
>                 going  down.   Since  7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values, but the actual timeout will decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases in decimal precision.

If you just want to check the http status code. You might want to check out the `--head` option.

I suggest using `--silent` with `--show-error` at the same time in case that you might want to know the error message.